# syntax error while compiling with ifort 11.0

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, syntax-error, intel, intel-fortran

I have a .F90 file having code something like

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC  :: Byte    = SELECTED_INT_KIND(1)   ! Byte  integer
INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC  :: Short   = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)   ! Short integer
INTEGER, PARAMETER, DIMENSION( N_IP_KINDS ), PRIVATE :: IP_KIND_TYPES = (/ Byte,Short /)
```

It is compiling successfully with `ifort 12`, But when i compile using `ifort 11.0`
it gives following error

`ABC.f90(275): error #5082: Syntax error, found &#39;,&#39; when expecting one of: ( %% : . = =&gt;
  INTEGER, PARAMETER, DIMENSION( N_IP_KINDS ), PRIVATE :: IP_KIND_TYPES = (/ Byte,  &amp;`

It looks like compiler bug.
Can anybody tell how to compile this using `ifort 11.0` by making any changes in source code

Comment: Where, and how, is `N_IP_KINDS` declared and defined ?

Comment: Do not bother about that, `N_IP_KINDS` is declayed. actually the code is very big i cant post all of that.

Comment: Please show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem. "Something like" almost always omits the key element, and it is clear from the error message that your actual code is NOT what you showed. It can be just the complete statement in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a well know bug in `ifort 11.0`

You can overcome this by 2 two ways

1: By upgrade your compiler to `ifort 12`
2: Modify your source code as below

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC  :: Byte    = SELECTED_INT_KIND(1)   ! Byte  integer
INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC  :: Short   = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)   ! Short integer
INTEGER, PARAMETER, DIMENSION( N_IP_KINDS ), PRIVATE :: IP_KIND_TYPES = (/ SELECTED_INT_KIND(1),SELECTED_INT_KIND(4) /)
```